# Why is this character invisible in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I've got a file, on which I'm doing some Regex. The file uses [ASCII character 218](http://www.asciitable.com/), which is visible in notepad. When I copy the character into my VS2010, it doesn't appear! But it will still cause a compile error if I paste it in the wrong place, and when I run the program, it still appears in the search string when I mouse over it. The regex works correctly.

The problem is of course that you can't see it in the code! How do I fix this, and what is causing it?

Comment: Are notepad and visual studio using the same font?

Comment: try to change the font you are using. Good pick would like "Lucida Console"

Comment: I'm using **Consolas** font and it's visible

Comment: Right, suppose I want the char as part of a string. Is there an elegant way to make it so? "\xDATheRestOfMyString"?

Comment: You can do it exactly that way yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Regex you can use the hex representation of the character in stead: \xDA

Answer (score 2):

The font that is used to display the code doesn't have a glyph for the character code 218.

To enter characters outside the general visible set of characters, use an escape code to enter it as a character code:

```
char strangeChar = '\u00da';
```

(The decimal numer 218 is the hexadecimal number 0xDA.)